# How to Convert Regex Pattern Match to Lowercase for URL Standardization/Tidying

Tags: html, regex, bash, url, awk

I am currently trying to convert all links and files and tags on my site from `UPPERCASE.ext` and `CamelCase.ext` to `lowercase.ext`.

I can match the links in pages using a regular expression match for `href="[^"]*"` and `src="[^"]*"`
This seems to work fine for identifying the link and images in the HTML.

However what I need to do with this is to take the match and run a `ToLowercase()` function on the matches. Since I have a lot of pages that I'd like to parse through, I'm looking to make a short shell script that will run on a specified directory and pattern match the specified regexes and perform a lowercase operation on them.

Comment: Checked sed transform `y`? http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-49

Answer (score 2):

Perl one-liner to rename all regular files to lowercase:

```
perl -le 'use File::Find; find({wanted=>sub{-f && rename($_, lc)}}, "/path/to/files");'
```

If you want to be more specific about what files are renamed you could change `-f` to a regex or something:

```
perl -le 'use File::Find; find({wanted=>sub{/\.(txt|htm|blah)$/i && rename($_, lc)}}, "/path/to/files");'
```

EDIT: Sorry, after rereading the question I see you also want to replace occurrences *within* files as well:

```
find /path/to/files -name "*.html" -exec perl -pi -e 's/\b(src|href)="(.+)"/$1="\L$2"/gi;' {} \;
```

EDIT 2: Try this one as the `find` command uses `+` instead of `\;` which is more efficient since multiple files are passed to perl at once (thanks to @ikegami from another post).  It also It also handles both `'` and `"` around the URL. Finally, it uses `{}` instead of `//` for substitutions since you are substituting URLs (maybe the `/`s in the URL are confusing perl or your shell?).  It shouldn't matter, and I tried both on my system with the same effect (both worked fine), but it's worth a shot:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec perl -pi -e \
    '$q=qr/"|\x39/; s{\b(src|href)=($q?.+$q?)\b}{$1=\L$2}gi;' {} +
```

PS: I also have a Macbook and tested these using bash shell with Perl versions 5.8.9 and 5.10.0.

Comment: Thanks. Receiving the error message "Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1." though. Syntax error?

Comment: Which command?  It shouldn't matter because I just pasted all three commands into my terminal and they ran correctly...

Comment: I tried the final one as that is the one that you indicated would work within files. Perhaps this is a problem with the build/version of perl? I am using a Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

you want this?

```
kent$  echo "aBcDEF"|sed 's/.*/\L&/g'
abcdef
```

or this

```
kent$  echo "aBcDEF"|awk '$0=tolower($0)'
abcdef
```

with your own regex:

```
kent$  echo 'FOO src="htTP://wWw.GOOGLE.CoM" BAR BlahBlah'|sed -r 's/src="[^"]*"/\L&/g'   
FOO src="http://www.google.com" BAR BlahBlah
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash, you can declare a variable to only hold lower case values:

```
declare -l varname
read varname <<< "This Is LOWERCASE"
echo $varname  # ==> this is lowercase
```

Or, you can convert a value to lowercase (bash version 4, I think)

```
x="This Is LOWERCASE"
echo ${x,,}  # ==> this is lowercase
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` with `-i` (in-place edit):

```
sed -i'' -re's/(href|src)="[^"]*"/\L&/g' /path/to/files/*
```

Comment: Is there a syntax error in this example? When I try this on my Macbook I receive the message:

sed: 1: "/path/to/files/ ...": command a expects \ followed by text

(Obviously /path/to/files/ is not what I am putting in as the path.)

Comment: Note that there is a `*` (star) at the end. `sed` doesn't expect a directory but one or more files. Using a filemask, your shell should expand the path to the matching files (I used `*` which means "all files").

Comment: The * was included in the file path.

Comment: Maybe your shell does not expand filemasks into files. You may use xargs for this purpose: `ls /path/to/files/* | xargs sed -i'' -re's/(href|src)="[^"]*"/\L&/g'`.
If you have spaces within filenames you will need something like this instead:  
`find /path/to/files/ -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i'' -re's/(href|src)="[^"]*"/\L&/g'` or, with -exec:  
`find /path/to/files/ -maxdepth 1 -exec sed -i'' -re's/(href|src)="[^"]*"/\L&/g' "{}"\;`